# Referencing Local resources from C# on Xamarin Platform

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am building an app on the Xamarin.Forms platform. I am creating a custom rendered list view, based on  [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Monkeys/blob/master/Monkeys-XAML-UI/Monkeys/Monkeys/ViewModels/MonkeysViewModel.cs) example. As you can see from the code reproduced below, I need to reference an image file, which is done using a web URL. Is it possible to reference a local image, i.e. a resource which is shipped with the app so this isn't web dependent.

```
  Monkeys = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();
  Monkeys.Add(new Monkey
  {
    Name = "Baboon",
    Location = "Africa & Asia",
    Details = "Baboons are African and Arabian Old World monkeys belonging to the genus Papio, part of the subfamily Cercopithecinae.",
    Image = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg/200px-Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg"
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
Image = "myimage.png"
```

And than add `myimage.png` to Resources in iOS (ensure build action `BundleResource`) and into drawable in Android (build action `AndroidResource`). You can use resource selector postfixes like `@2x, @3x` on iOS and use folders with resource selectors `drawable-mdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-...` on Android as well.

For more info have a look at: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Local_Images